# Any browser can be used to simulate Safari to some extent

Tags: css, windows, safari

I wonder which other browser/version is more similar to Safari 9/10 at the moment.

The Safari on Mac has trouble rendering some of my flex-based web pages and installing all of my dev tools on a macOS is all headache (that is not reporducable on all window browsers that I have tried).

So perhaps there is a Windows based browser that can be used at least to some extends to simulate Safari webkit engine on Windows.

Clearly services like browser stack are not not what I am looking for.